# What is the link between path integral source terms and the propagator?

Tags: path-integral, diffusion, propagator, noise

Consider a diffusion process defined by
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial ^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}$$
where $\phi$ is the probability density of a particle's position and $D$ is the diffusion coefficient (or whatever it's called).
Denote the transition probability to go from $(0,0)$ to $(x,t)$ as $W(x,t;0,0)$.
It's easy enough to show that
$$W(x_f,t;0,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}} \exp \left( -\frac{x_f^2}{4 D t}\right) \, .$$
We can imagine getting this result by summing the probabilities of all possible paths starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(x,t)$ $[a]$.
We can approximate this sum over all paths by dividing the time axis into $n+1$ slices of length $\epsilon$.
Note that the $0^\text{th}$ slice is the starting point where the position is constrianed to be $x=0$ and the $(N+1)^\text{th}$ slice is the end point where the position is constrained to be $x=x_f$.

Using the known solution to the diffusion over each time slice, we can write $[b]$
\begin{align}
W(x,t;0,0)
=& \int dx_1 \cdots dx_n \left( \frac{1}{4 \pi D \epsilon} \right)^{n/2} \exp \left[ - \frac{1}{4D\epsilon} \sum_{i=0}^n (x_{i+1} - x_i)^2\right] \\
=& \int dx_1 \cdots dx_n \left( \frac{1}{4 \pi D \epsilon} \right)^{n/2} \exp \left[ - \frac{1}{4D\epsilon} \left( \sum_{ij} x_i A_{ij} x_j + \sum_i x_i J_i \right) - \frac{1}{4 D \epsilon} x_f^2 \right]
\end{align}
where
$$A_{ij} = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
2&-1&&&\\
-1&2&-1&&\\
&-1&\ddots&-1&\\
&&-1&2&-1\\
&&&-1&2
\end{array}\right]$$
is the discrete version of the second derivative, and $J$, which depends on the boundary conditions, is in this particular case $J_i = 2 \delta_{i,n} x_f$.

There's a known formula
$$\int dx_1 \cdots dx_n \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{ij}A_{ij}x_i x_j + \sum_i J_i x_i \right] = \sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{\text{det}A}} \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} \sum_{ij} J_i (A^{-1})_{ij} J_j \right) \, .$$

I don't know $A^{-1}$, so I can't evaluate the expression.
However, I am given to believe that there is a link between $A^{-1}$ and the propagator $W(x_f, t_f; x_i, t_i)$.
If that's true, then I should be able to work out the term involving the $J$'s because I know the propagator.

What is the link between $A^{-1}$ and $W$, and how can I use that link to evaluate $\sum_{ij} J_i (A^{-1})_{ij} J_j$?

$[a]$: i.e. we can invent the path integral.

$[b]$: Yes, I'm using the known solution to rewrite the problem as an integral. This looks like circular reasoning but the point is to get things into a form suitable for more complex problems.

Comment: Your matrix $A$, being tridiagonal, probably has a rather simple inverse (for one thing, its eigenvalues and eigenvectors are known; I'm on my phone so I cant look them up now, but I know that there are closed form expressions for them). You could try to find the inverse for $N=1,2,3,...$ and try to find a pattern.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks, I will see if the inverse is known. That said, this question is more conceptual: is there a way to not have to invert the matrix and instead use known properties of the propagator?

Comment: There is a clear pattern. So far I can discern, $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{N+1} \begin{pmatrix}
N & N-1 & \dots & 1\\ 
 &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  & \\ 
1 & \dots &N-1  & N 
\end{pmatrix}$ and the middle definitely has a pattern to it as well but I haven't quite cracked it.

Comment: @DanielSank yes, I know that your question is not really about the inverse. In any case, you can find the explicit form of the inverse in [Analytical inversion of symmetric tridiagonal matrices](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/29/7/020), eq. (10). See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Inversion).

Comment: The matrix $A$ has the form of the Cartan matrix for $A_n$ Lie algebras as given in Slansky's article http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf table 6 page 81 (first matrix). Its inverse is given by the first matrix $G$ in page 82, from which one can deduce that its determinant is $n+1$. The exponential factor $JA^{-1}J$ depends only on the last entry of $G$, which is $n/(n+1)$. Substituting this data into your equations recovers the initial propagator.

Comment: cont. . I think that the full form of $G$ the inverse of the discrete Laplacian should become important when you consider a diffusion equation with sources.